# wait(NULL) seems to cause child to stop executing

Tags: c++, pipe, fork, wait

I'm writing a simple pipe program that will ask for two commands then run the programs as if they were entered into bash as `cmd1 | cmd2`. Then it should loop and ask again until one of the commands is `quit`.

I've already written this much:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int pid1, pid2, errchk;
    int pip[2];
    char cmd1[128];
    char cmd2[128];
    int i = 0;
    int status;

    errchk = pipe(pip);//make pipe
    if(errchk == -1)//check for error in pipe
    {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(i<3)
    {
        i++;
        //Enter commands here
        cout<<"Enter cmd1: ";
        cin>>cmd1;
        cout<<"Enter cmd2: ";
        cin>>cmd2;
        //if a command is quit... quit
        if(strcmp(cmd1,"quit")==0 || strcmp(cmd2,"quit") == 0)
        {
            cout<<"Quitting...\n";
            exit(1);
        }

        pid1 = fork();
        cout<<"first fork makes pids: "<<pid1<<endl;
        if(pid1 < 0)
        {
            perror("fork");
            exit(1);
        }

        else if(pid1 == 0) //MAIN CHILD
        {
            cout<<"In main child with pid: "<<pid1<<endl;
            pid2 = fork();
            cout<<"second fork makes pids: "<<pid2<<endl;
            if(pid2 == 0)//SUB CHILD 2 to run cmd2
            {
                cout<<"In child of second fork"<<endl;
                close(0);
                close(pip[1]);
                dup(pip[0]);
                execvp(cmd2,argv);//execute command2 and die
            }
            else if(pid2 > 0)//SUB CHILD 1 to run cmd1
            {
                cout<<"In parent of second fork"<<endl;
                close(1);
                close(pip[0]);
                dup(pip[1]);
                execvp(cmd1,argv);//execute command1 and die
            }
        }
        else if(pid1 > 0) //MAIN PARENT
        {
            wait(NULL);//wait for cmd1
            wait(NULL);//wait for cmd2
            cout<<"DONE executing"<<endl; //keep going
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it and enter `ls` and `wc`
The output I get is:

```
Enter cmd1: ls
Enter cmd2: wc
first fork makes pids: 5785
first fork makes pids: 0
In main child with pid: 0
second fork makes pids: 5786
In parent of second fork
second fork makes pids: 0
In child of second fork
DONE executing
      5       5      54
```

The main problem I have is that I should have `Done executing` come after `ls|wc` not the other way around.
I'm thinking the `wait(NULL)` isn't working but I'm not sure.

Please advise.
And Thank you.

Comment: You cannot wait for a grandchild.  child1 has to wait for child2

Comment: The lines `cin>>cmd1;` and `cin>>cmd2;` can overflow the arrays if a malicious user types a long enough string without whitespace, causing Undefined Behavior. This is C++, so please just use `std::string`, not `char[128]`.

Comment: I have to use char since execvp won't work with strings.

Comment: I ended up using execvp with strtok in order to run my commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
parent
  1. child1
    2. child2
    2. exec()
  1. exec()
```

When you exec in child1, child2 gets reparented to init, and you can no longer wait for child2 to terminate.

So we need to do a little bit of refactoring to get something looking like:

```
parent
  1. child1
  1. exec()
  2. child2
  2. exec()
wait() x 2
```

Basing this on your own code, with the refactoring to accomplish something like the look-alike code (some comments in-line):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int pid1, pid2, errchk;
    int pip[2];
    char cmd1[128];
    char cmd2[128];
    int status;

    while(true)
    {
        errchk = pipe(pip);//make pipe
        if(errchk == -1)//check for error in pipe
        {
            perror("pipe");
            exit(1);
        }

        //Enter commands here
        cout<<"Enter cmd1: ";
        cin>>cmd1;
        cout<<"Enter cmd2: ";
        cin>>cmd2;
        //if a command is quit... quit
        if(strcmp(cmd1,"quit")==0 || strcmp(cmd2,"quit") == 0)
        {
            cout<<"Quitting...\n";
            exit(1);
        }

        pid1 = fork();
        cout<<"first fork makes pids: "<<pid1<<endl;
        if(pid1 < 0)
        {
            perror("fork");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (pid1 == 0) // in child
        {
            cout<<"In child of first fork"<<endl;
            close(pip[0]); // close read-end of pipe
            close(0); // close stdin
            close(1); // close stdout
            dup2(pip[1], 1); // write-end of pipe is stdout of cmd1
            argv[0] = cmd1; // make it look like the command in the ps output
            execvp(cmd1,argv);//execute command1 and die
            fprintf(stderr, "execvp(1): `%s': %s\n", cmd1, strerror(errno));
            return 0;
        }
        pid2 = fork();
        cout<<"second fork makes pids: "<<pid2<<endl;
        if (pid2 < 0)
        {
            perror("fork2");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (pid2 == 0)
        {
            cout<<"In child of second fork"<<endl;
            close(pip[1]); // close write-end of pipe
            close(0); // close stdin
            dup2(pip[0], 0); // read-end of pipe is stdin of cmd2
            argv[0] = cmd2; // update ps output
            execvp(cmd2,argv);//execute command2 and die
            fprintf(stderr, "execvp(1): `%s': %s\n", cmd2, strerror(errno));
            return 0;
        }
        if(pid1 > 0) //MAIN PARENT
        {
            // close remaining pipe handles in parent
            close(pip[0]);
            close(pip[1]);
            wait(0);//wait for one command to run
            wait(0);//wait for a second command to run
            cout<<"DONE executing"<<endl; //keep going
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I realized what you're doing now - I made an error in the original answer. I'll need to edit the answer

Comment: I moved the while loop above the pipe and made its condition `true` so that it can continuously ask for 2 commands, execute and then ask for 2 more etc... But on the first run through with putting in `ls` and `wc` it shows `0   0   0` then on the second it starts to give correct data? Any ideas as to why?

Comment: yeah, it would have only worked on the first time round, so moving the pipe inside the while loop was a fix to my changes. I don't know why you're getting a `0 0 0` on the first time round - if the execvp failed you might see that so I've gone ahead and made an additional error check after both execvps to display an error message in that case.

Comment: Is it possible to print out the error using perror?

Comment: You can replace the fprintf with a simple perror - the reason I used the fprintf was to get the command that was being invoked, so it can be checked for a typo, etc